# Pushing to heroku is gets rejected

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, vue.js, quasar

I am building an application with Vue and Quasar and deploying the application to heroku in a new branch. It was working fine but one day after I have given this command 
`git push heroku new_branch:master` 
it showed this error. 
N.B. I have run `git add --all` and `git commit -m "commit"` command before giving the git push command

```
 make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o] Error 1
remote:        make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/node_modules/grpc/build'
remote:        gyp ERR! build error 
remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:254:12)
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1031-aws
remote:        gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/node_modules/grpc
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v11.2.0
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok 
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:978:16)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:265:5)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1031-aws
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/node_modules/grpc
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v11.2.0
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
remote:        Failed to execute '/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.o
remote:        make: *** No rule to make target 'Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_args.o', needed by 'Release/obj.target/libgrpc.a'.  Stop.
remote:        make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/node_modules/grpc/build'
remote:        gyp ERR! build error 
remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:254:12)
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1031-aws
remote:        gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v67-linux-x64-glibc" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_63a4fab0f7b2e069ece0d7b9506926ed/node_modules/grpc
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v11.2.0
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok 
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 1
remote:        npm ERR! grpc@1.13.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.13.1 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.giDB1/_logs/2018-11-16T07_10_19_788Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:        
remote:        - Dangerous semver range (>) in engines.node
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to gentle-lake-22251.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/gentle-lake-22251.git
 ! [remote rejected] new_branch -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/gentle-lake-22251.git
```

Can someone help?

Comment: I guess, you are behind a firewall/proxy which restricts git push.

Comment: Did you `git --amend` or in any way alter the history of the git repository? Try using `git push --force`